# reset usb when usb fails without plug and unplug?

Tags: android, usb

when plug a usb device, the host can't reconglize the usb device. It's means the usb list fails.
In the development enviroment, It must be reliability. I can't unplug the device, but Device may be failure when reboot for many times. 
The linux kernel will have uevent to report the usb fails?
How Can I reset the usb device without plug and unplug?